# Why does the author define the table fields in two position in Room with Android Jetpack?

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

I'm learning Android Jetpack, the following code is from a sample project at https://github.com/android/sunflower.

The [GardenPlanting.kt](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/data/GardenPlanting.kt) code is to design a table, I'm very strange why the author define the table fields in two position, you see that  `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)  @ColumnInfo(name = "id")` is located the inner of the class.

I think that Code B is easy to understand, right?

**GardenPlanting.kt**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "garden_plantings",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = Plant::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["plant_id"])
    ],
    indices = [Index("plant_id")]
)

data class GardenPlanting(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "plant_id") val plantId: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "plant_date") val plantDate: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance(),    

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_watering_date")
    val lastWateringDate: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
) {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
        var gardenPlantingId: Long = 0
}
```

**Code B**

```
data class GardenPlanting(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id")  val id: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "plant_id") val plantId: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "plant_date") val plantDate: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance(),

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_watering_date")
    val lastWateringDate: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
) {

        var gardenPlantingId: Long = 0
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration of a property inside the `data` class constructor is used to :

1. Generate [component](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) function for destructing
2. Use these fields inside the `toString()`, `equals()`, `hashCode()`, and `copy()`

So if you want to avoid copying fields with the `copy` method then the easy way is to declare the fields inside the body of the class.

Example:

```
fun main() {
    val user = User("Pavneet", "29k+")
    user.id = kotlin.random.Random.nextInt(10, 20)
    val userCopy = user.copy()
    println(userCopy) // id won't be printed 'cuz it's not a part of toString method
    userCopy.id = 99
    print(userCopy.equals(user)) // true, 'cuz id is not being used by the equals method
    //var(name, repo, id) = userCopy // error, User must have a 'component3()' function
    var(name, repo) = userCopy

}

data class User(val name: String = "", val repo:String="0"){
    var id:Int = 0
}
```

Advantages:

1. Create a copies of the object excluding specific fields
2. Exclude specific fields to compare two objects with equals
3. Exclude specific fields in destructuring declarations

Note: `copy` and `component` methods cannot be provided explicitly(inside data class). In example B, `gardenPlantingId` is replaced with `id` so can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple:

Because in this sample code, the author wants to show that we can use both `@PrimaryKey` and `@ColumnInfo` annotation to **ANY** member inside an entity class, regardless its position (it can be in the inside the constructor or at the outside).

To experiment with this, you can just do exactly what you did on **Code B**. It is also valid, but in that case, `gardenPlantingId` will not have a custom column name because we don't use `@ColumnInfo` annotation.  Also, it is not necessary to declare `@PrimaryKey` outside the constructor (like the given example). You can just declare your the primary key annotation inside the constructor.